# What does this Groovy Function does

Tags: linux, security, groovy, centos, base64

```
sun.misc.BASE64Decoder TGJfB = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
byte[] htIVP = TGJfB.decodeBuffer("cm0gL3RtcC95Z0ZEN0I=");
String [] PHaar = new String[3];
PHaar[0] = "/bin/sh";
PHaar[1] = "-c";
PHaar[2] = new String(htIVP, "UTF-8");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PHaar);
```

I found this code in my server What does this do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cm0gL3RtcC95Z0ZEN0I=` base64 encoding string contains this clear text : `rm /tmp/ygFD7B`

The equivalent of that code is to execute this in your shell:

```
/bin/sh -c 'rm /tmp/ygFD7B'
```

I hope you have no important data here **;-)** !

Comment: I really dont anything about groovy What does this code Do

Comment: @NijeeshKJ This Java code (hardly Groovy at all) executes a shell which then removes the file `/tmp/ygFD7B`.  Why someone is going all that measure is beyond me.  The fact, that they "hid" the command in that base64 string could indicate malicious intentions.  Also given the fact they used `sh -c'...'` its most likely used to transport any shell script/commands over.

Comment: I agree with @cfrick it's seems malicous code, try to see what is the content of the directory (and where/when is it created)